# Is the Raspberry Pi compatible with HDMI 1.4 specification with Ethernet?

Tags: hdmi

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi#Specifications) says the Raspberry Pi supports "HDMI (rev 1.3 & 1.4)" and the [HDMI 1.4 specification has Ethernet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#Version_1.4). Could you have a HDMI 1.4 to Ethernet adapter? and would the transfer rate be faster than USB 2.0?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As stated and tested [here](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=6378&p=83015), Raspberry PI does not support HDMI Ethernet Channel.

Comment: Any official documentation from the Raspberry Pi foundation?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the [schematics of Model A and B Revision 2.1](https://web.archive.org/web/20160305080241/https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/schematics/Raspberry-Pi-Rev-2.1-Model-AB-Schematics.pdf), page 2, as well as the [schematics of Model B+ Revision 1.2](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/rpi/raspberry-pi-b-plus-reduced-schematics.pdf), page 1, we find that the pin 14 at the HDMI connector is not connected. This pin is responsible for the HDMI-Ethernet-Channel (HEC) for HDMI 1.4 and reserved for HDMI 1.0-1.3.

So there's no HDMI ethernet connected on the Pi A/A+/B/B+ (and presumably neither on the Pi 2 and the Pi Zero).